# How to filter child array data in mongodb collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The following code joins 'cruises' and 'rooms' collections.

```
    dbo.collection('cruises').aggregate([
      { $lookup: {from: 'rooms', localField: 'roomTypes.roomID', foreignField: 'roomID', as: 'roomTypes'} },
      { 
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
          'roomTypes': {
            _id: 0
          }
        }
      }
    ]).toArray(function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        logger.error(`getCruises : Error reading cruises db`);
        logger.error(`  Error: ${err}`);
        callback(err, null);
      } else {
        let cruisesData = data;
        callback(null, cruisesData);
      }
    });
```

to produce the following output. The `roomTypes` comes from 'rooms' collection.

```
[
{
  "cruiseID": "00001",
  "title": "some title",
  "description": "some desc"
  "roomTypes": [
    {
      "roomID": "IPD",
      "roomDetails": {
        "roomType": "some type",
        "title": "some title",
        "description": "desc",
        "maxOccupants": 2
      },
      "capacity": [
        {
          "cruiseID": "00001",
          "available": 20
        },{
          "cruiseID": "00002",
          "available": 10
        }
      ]
},
{
  "cruiseID": "00002",
  "title": "some other title",
  "description": "some other desc"
  "roomTypes": [
    {
      "roomID": "IPD",
      "roomDetails": {
        "roomType": "some type",
        "title": "some title",
        "description": "desc",
        "maxOccupants": 2
      },
      "capacity": [
        {
          "cruiseID": "00001",
          "available": 20
        },{
          "cruiseID": "00002",
          "available": 10
        }
      ]
}
]
```

How do I change it to get the following output. I.e. to show the capacity for the matching `cruiseID`. If it would be easier to achieve it with changed data model, feel free to suggest it as well.

```
[
{
  "cruiseID": "00001",
  "title": "some title",
  "description": "some desc"
  "roomTypes": [
    {
      "roomID": "IPD",
      "roomDetails": {
        "roomType": "some type",
        "title": "some title",
        "description": "desc",
        "maxOccupants": 2
      },
      "capacity": 20
},
{
  "cruiseID": "00002",
  "title": "some other title",
  "description": "some other desc"
  "roomTypes": [
    {
      "roomID": "IPD",
      "roomDetails": {
        "roomType": "some type",
        "title": "some title",
        "description": "desc",
        "maxOccupants": 2
      },
      "capacity": 10
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a extra pipeline stage at the end of your pipeline stages,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `roomTypes` array
- `$reduce` to check condition if `cruiseID` match then return available
- `$mergeObjects` with current object of `roomTypes` and return document

```
  // <= skipping your pipeline stages
  {
    $addFields: {
      roomTypes: {
        $map: {
          input: "$roomTypes",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                capacity: {
                  $reduce: {
                    input: "$$this.capacity",
                    initialValue: 0,
                    in: {
                      $cond: [
                        { $eq: ["$$this.cruiseID", "$cruiseID"] },
                        "$$this.available",
                        "$$value"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qnjP1dNqdnZ)

---

Second possible way you can do this,

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3Eb44wp-pcF)

Comment: awesome, i didn't know of that tool until now.

Comment: Is there a simple way for returning "available": 20 instead of "capacity": 20? i.e. rename capacity to available?

Comment: I tried adding ```{ $rename: { 'capacity': 'available' } }``` but it doesn't seem to be allowed as a pipeline stage

Comment: @Przemek i have updated both the playground links in answer.

Comment: @turivishal - thanks. I was very close with my trial and error. I didn't know the order of things in the pipeline matters that much - I had the $project before the $addFields

Answer (score 1):

You could do a simple array mapping.

> Note:
>
> This is just a workaround, you could probably improve your schema or
> query or something.

Here's the code. Basically just map the nested `capacity` property of each **cruise** and use `find` method to find the matching capacity and pluck the **available** property.

```js
var data = [{
    "cruiseID": "00001",
    "title": "some title",
    "description": "some desc",
    "roomTypes": [{
      "roomID": "IPD",
      "roomDetails": {
        "roomType": "some type",
        "title": "some title",
        "description": "desc",
        "maxOccupants": 2
      },
      "capacity": [{
        "cruiseID": "00001",
        "available": 20
      }, {
        "cruiseID": "00002",
        "available": 10
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    "cruiseID": "00002",
    "title": "some other title",
    "description": "some other desc",
    "roomTypes": [{
      "roomID": "IPD",
      "roomDetails": {
        "roomType": "some type",
        "title": "some title",
        "description": "desc",
        "maxOccupants": 2
      },
      "capacity": [{
        "cruiseID": "00001",
        "available": 20
      }, {
        "cruiseID": "00002",
        "available": 10
      }]
    }]
  }
]


var test = data.map(cruise => {
  return {
    ...cruise,
    roomTypes: cruise.roomTypes.map(room => {
      return {
        ...room,
        capacity: room.capacity.find(c => c.cruiseID === cruise.cruiseID).available
      }
    })
  }
});

console.log(test);
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. However, I was looking for changing my mongo query to get it directly without manipulating afterwards.

Comment: @Przemek, the accepted answer is indeed the better answer. I'm also learning mongodb right now so i'm still learning something new as well. :)